# Put postgres function files in classpath and execute on Spring Boot start up event, it is a good idea?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I have a project with many postgres's function and currently every time that theses ones are updated we must run manually in postgresql server so I want automatize theses updates using start up event of my spring boot project reading all sql files and executing directly with jdbctemplate or something but I don't know is this is a good practices to do or maybe could be make into problems. All my postgrest's function files have 'CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a library that will handle database migrations for you. You will have to configure the library, define all your SQL (tables, functions, etc) in script files that are then executed when your application starts if necessary.

Two very popular examples of such libraries are [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) and [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/).

There is a lot of information online for using both of these libraries.